# how to remove an item from a dictionary that is iterated?

Tags: python, dictionary, loops

I have a dictionary with timestamps and I want to iterate through it and remove the items that are considered outdated (in Python)
How do I best go about this?
This code gives me **RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration**:

```
    for key, value in img_dict.iteritems() :
        if (time.time()-float(img_dict[key])) >= stale_img:
            logger.debug('STALE IMAGE FROM '+hexlify(key)+ ' - GOT CLOSED NOW!')
            del img_dict[key]
            data_upload = True
```

Comment: This isn't your problem, but: Why are you using `for key, value in img_dict.iteritems():` instead of `for key in img_dict:`, given that you're not using `value` anywhere, and are in fact explicitly doing `img_dict[key]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't modify collections while iterating over them.

There are a few ways around this:

- (0) Rethink your design to see if you need to do this.
- (1) Don't modify the collection; instead, build a new, filtered collection.
- (2) Don't iterate over the collection; instead, iterate over a copy of the collection
- (2.5) For a dictionary, iterate over a copy of the keys, and fetch the values explicitly.

Note that you're already fetching the values explicitly, despite iterating over the items, so there's no reason to go with #2 here.

Here are implementations of the other two:

```
new_img_dict = {}
for key in img_dict:
    if (time.time()-float(img_dict[key])) >= stale_img:
        logger.debug('STALE IMAGE FROM '+hexlify(key)+ ' - GOT CLOSED NOW!')
        data_upload = True
   else:
       new_img_dict[key] = img_dict[key]
img_dict = new_img_dict
```

Or:

```
for key in img_dict.keys():
    if (time.time()-float(img_dict[key])) >= stale_img:
        logger.debug('STALE IMAGE FROM '+hexlify(key)+ ' - GOT CLOSED NOW!')
        del img_dict[key]
        data_upload = True
```

(If you want this to be Python 3 compatible, instead of `img_dict.keys()`, do `img_dict.keys()[:]`.)

So, how do you choose between the two?

The first is generally easier to reason about—in general, immutable objects and pure operations are easy to reason about. For example, if you throw an exception somewhere, `img_dict` will always have the original version or the completed version, not something half-way in between. And of course you don't have to think through what it means to change something while iterating over it. However, in some rare cases, it's hard to transform your "delete everything where foo" algorithm into a "copy everything where not foo" algorithm.

The first one is also usually much easier to rewrite as a comprehension (or a call to a higher-order function like `filter`), turn into a generator, refactor to pull out separate functions, etc.

For performance, the first one will generally be faster and use less memory if you're filtering out many values, while the second will usually be better if you're keeping most values. (The cutoff is different for different collection types. As usually, it rarely matters, and if it does, you should write it both ways and profile.)

Coming back to #0, I think it might apply in this case. You're walking through all of the keys to see if any are too old, to remove them. If you used, say, a sorted list, or a priority queue, you wouldn't have to do that. Now, if you need to use the collection as a `dict` more often than you need to flush the old values, you'd probably get more cost than benefit from changing the data structure. But why not have both? If you had a sorted list of keys, on top of the dictionary mapping keys to values, then you could just do this:

```
for key in img_sorted_key_list:
    if time.time() - float(key) > stale_img:
        break
    del img_dict[key]
```

Or, more simply:

```
stale_time = time.time() - stale_img
for key in itertools.takewhile(lambda key: float(key) < stale_time, 
                               img_sorted_key_list):
    del img_dict[key]
```

And you could wrap the sorted key list and the dictionary together into a nice `Cache` class or something.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example. Maybe it  will be helpful. Remember, when you deleting an element in a list or dictionary start from the end. Avoid to use *iteritems()* method.

```
keysMap = [
      {"key": 1 },
      {"key" : 2 },
      {"key" : 3 },
      {"key" : 4 },
      {"key" : 5 },
      {"key" : 6 }
       ]   
i=len(keysMap)-1
while i > 0 :
    key = keysMap[i]
    if key["key"]==2 :
        del(keysMap[i])
    i=i-1

# Printing the object data after deleting element key=2    
while i < len(keysMap) :
    key = keysMap[i]
    print key
    i=i+1
```